# How can I write a script to create a queue to submit jobs for terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, batch

I have several input files for a program installed in my ubuntu, I can do it manually and put

```
keyword teste.in
```

But since I have a really large number of files all with different names I would like to make this automatic. Is it possible to create a queue here the script submits the first job and when this is finished it submits the following one and then all the others one at a time?

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what it is you want to do, with a more complete example?

Comment: I'm using a program called QE that is a modelling code that reads a quite complex input file name.in
So, I've several ZZYX.in XXY2.in YZX3.in .... and I need to run all of them after each other.
Usual to run I need to write in the command line
~qe name.in

but now I would like to make a queue like a script that submits one after each other with qe inputname.in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like the following. Suppose I have several files in a directory, in my little test case I have three files called a.txt b.txt c.txt. Then in bash I can use a for loop like this:

```
for name in `ls` ; do echo now name is $name ; cat $name ; done
```

The variable $name will contain the current filename, and it will loop through all the filenames listed by the ls command. Of course, instead of the "cat $name" that I used for my test, you would use your own command, like "qe $name" or whatever.

If you don't like separating things with semicolons as above, you can instead write it on separate lines in a script file, like this:

```
for name in `ls` ; do
  echo now name is $name
  cat $name
done
```

The "echo now name is $name" part is not necessary, it is just something I like to have to see what the script is doing.

Comment: @user9251343 Great, set it as "accepted" answer then :-)